# Perl regex match ignoring order

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to compare a variable and another variable in regex form. If the contents of the variables are exactly the same, match happens fine but if the order of the values are different, I want the match to happen.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $output  = "test0 test1";
my $expected_output = "test1 test0";
 my $expected_regex = qr/^$expected_output\s*$/;
print "Expected_regex ::  $expected_regex\n";
 if ($output =~ $expected_regex) {
   print "pass\n";
}
```

In my example, what can I do to make `$output = $expected_regex` even though they contain the same values but not in the same order?

Comment: If your input patterns are not "as simple" as what you stated here, please edit your question with a (short but representative) "real life" example, so we have a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

**Assuming** your inputs are really "that simple", i.e. words separated by spaces, you can do something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $output  = "test0 test1";
my $expected_output = "test1 test0";

# Store the sorted pieces of each string in a list
my @o = sort(split(/ /, $output));
my @e = sort(split(/ /, $expected_output));

# Compare both arrays for equality of each member
print "pass\n" if (@o ~~ @e);
```

See [smart matching in detail](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) for the funny `~~` operator.

If your inputs are not that simple, the `/ /` in the splits could possibly be elaborated, or a similar technique could be derived.

If not, just keep the first two lines of this and put it in all your non-trivial scripts. That's sure to help you.

Comment: Sometimes it's not about doing thing with the tool you picked up, but letting you know about a tool that is better suited for your job.

Comment: Why use `-w` when you have `use warnings`? Isn't `-w` deprecated?

Comment: Humm... bad habit I guess. I don't even notice it :-/ I don't see anything about it being deprecated in `man perl` (but indeed, it's redundant). There's still `The -w switch is optional` in the _BUGS_ section though ;)